# Power calculation with multiple techniques and multiple observations per subject

Tags: mean, repeated-measures, statistical-power

Say I have `C` algorithms/techniques and `N` subjects. For each algorithm/technique I make some (variable) number of measurements per subject, and for each measurement I can calculate the error against a known ground truth. I would like to compare each algorithm's error and determine whether the differences are significant, while taking into account that there are multiple measurements per subject. Here is some dummy data to show how it could be structured:

| Subject_ID | Observation_ID | Algorithm_A_Error | Algorithm_B_Error | Algorithm_C_Error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.5 | 0.3 | 0.7 |
| 1 | 2 | 1.2 | 0.4 | 0.1 |
| 1 | 3 | 0.4 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.5 | 0.3 | 0.7 |
| 2 | 2 | 1.2 | 0.4 | 0.1 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.4 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| 2 | 4 | 0.4 | 0.2 | 0.2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I've organized observations row-wise to emphasize that there will be a different number of observations for each subject, but organized algorithms column-wise to emphasize that each all observations are made by each algorithm. My question is:

**What power calculation do I need to perform to determine the number of subjects `N` and the approximate number of observations I will need to determine the optimal method?** I can make estimates of the magnitude and errors I might expect.

Concrete details, in case relevant:

1. Each subject is an individual patient.
2. Each algorithm is an image registration technique. In reality I will have more algorithms, ~6.
3. Each observation corresponds to an independent anatomical location in the body. A different set of locations is selected for each patient, but any selected location will be measured with all algorithms.
4. Each error is a spatial distance between where I've annotated that a particular landmark is and where the registration algorithm has calculated that it should be.